# UIBarButtonItem with customView (UISwitch) disappears shortly after creating the toolbar (even though it's a really simple code!)

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, toolbar, uiswitch

I try to create a toolbar with a UIBarButtonItem with a customView (UISwitch). This is done by my function "createtoolbar()".

On viewDidLoad() the toolbar is created properly.

BUT: Creating the toolbar by pressing a Button, the UISwitch disappears approx. 0.1 seconds later.

Hope someone can help me! :)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createtoolbar()
}


@IBOutlet var bottomBar: UIToolbar!
let alarmSwitch = UISwitch()

func createtoolbar() {
    alarmSwitch.on = true
    let alarmSwitchBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: alarmSwitch)
    var toolbarbuttons = [alarmSwitchBarButton]
    bottomBar.setItems(toolbarbuttons, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func createtoolbarButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    createtoolbar()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do. You're creating the bar button item in code but adding a switch that's an IBOutlet? You can't do that -- if your switch actually is an IBOutlet, then it will already be the subview of some other view, and you can't use it in you bar button. If it's not an IBOutlet (which to shouldn't be), then you need to create the switch in code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is right, in my code above, the switch was an IBOutlet. So i created the switch in code.

PROBLEM: When i call createtoolbarplay() in the viewDidLoad(), everything is fine. BUT: When i call createtoolbarplay() with a Button, i have the same problem again...

Hope, you can help me?

Comment: @JustSmile, edit your question to show what you are doing now.

Comment: just updated my question: 1. I added the UISwitch now programmatically. 2. The problem is still up to date. 3. Hope for more help.

Comment: @JustSmile, I copied and pasted your code into a new app, and it worked fine, so I have no idea why you're still having a problem. If you can post your project somewhere that I can download it, I'll take a look.

Comment: I uploaded it on my server: http://www.lahmephotography.de/downloads/testfield.zip

Comment: So, what's the problem? I see the switch when I run your app. Is the problem that the button disappears when you touch the button? Why have that button method at all if you've already created the button by calling the method from viewDidLoad? I suspect the problem is that the switch is added to the toolbar initially (from viewDidLoad), and then you try to insert that same switch into a new bar button item even though its already a subview of the first bar button item that you created. You should only create this bar button item once.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem! It disappears after clicking the button! In my main-project i need to modify the toolbar. But you found the solution: Add the Switch to its BarButtonItem only once. Then it doesn't disappear any more, when i shuffle toolbar-buttons. A happy man from germany says: Thank you very much!